# Does "whose commit message matches the given regular expression" qualify "the youngest commit" or `rev`?

Tags: git

Git Pocket Guide says

> ```
> rev^regexp
> ```
>
> For example, `HEAD^{/"fixed  pr#1234"}`; this selects the youngest commit reachable from `rev` whose commit message matches the given regular expression.

Does "whose commit message matches the given regular expression" qualify "the youngest commit" or `rev`?

I am always uncertain about this and similar cases.

Comment: I've been using Git for years and I had no idea about this syntax. Very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

`rev` does. From [gitrevisions](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions)...

> `<rev>^{/<text>}`, e.g. `HEAD^{/fix nasty bug}`
>
> A suffix ^ to a revision parameter, followed by a brace pair that contains a
>              text led by a slash, is the same as the `:/fix nasty bug` syntax below except
>              that ***it returns the youngest matching commit which is reachable from the `<rev>`
>              before `^`***.

Note that it's not the youngest commit in the entire repo. It's the youngest commit ***reachable from the `<rev>`***. If you want the youngest in the whole repo use `:/<regexp>`.

> `:/<text>`, e.g. `:/fix nasty bug`
>
> A colon, followed by a slash, followed by a text, names a commit whose commit
>              message matches the specified regular expression. This name returns the ***youngest matching commit which is reachable from any ref, including HEAD***. The
>              regular expression can match any part of the commit message. To match messages
>              starting with a string, one can use e.g.  :/^foo. The special sequence :/!  is
>              reserved for modifiers to what is matched.  :/!-foo performs a negative match,
>              while :/!!foo matches a literal !  character, followed by foo. Any other
>              sequence beginning with :/!  is reserved for now. Depending on the given text,
>              the shell's word splitting rules might require additional quoting.

This makes more sense if you realize Git history is not like a big stack of pancakes. It's a [directed graph](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Graph_(abstract_data_type)). Git history looks like this...

```
------ time -------->

              [HEAD]
A <- B <- C <- D [master]
           ^
            \
             E <- F <- G [feature]
```

This shows a repository with the `master` branch checked out. It also has a `feature` branch which has younger commits than `master`. G is the youngest commit in the repository, but D is the youngest commit reachable by `master` and `HEAD`.

`HEAD^{/fix nasty bug}` will search for `fix nasty bug` in D, then C, then B, then A. Because the connections are one-way it will not search E, F, nor G because they cannot be reached from `HEAD`.